# steam OpenID authentication without a callback-URL

Tags: java, openid, easymock, google-openid, steam

I am trying how to add a steam logging to my java application .I have try out few OpenID libraries in http://openid.net/developers/libraries, And this is for JOpenID ,

Eg - >

```
    OpenIdManager manager = new OpenIdManager();

    manager.setTimeOut(10000);
    Endpoint endpoint = manager.lookupEndpoint("http://steamcommunity.com/openid");
    System.out.println(endpoint);
    Association association = manager.lookupAssociation(endpoint);
    System.out.println(association);
    String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(endpoint, association);
    System.out.println("Copy the authentication URL in browser:\n" + url);
    System.out.println("After successfully sign on in browser, enter the URL of address bar in browser:");

    String ret = url;
    HttpServletRequest request = createRequest(ret);
    Authentication authentication = manager.getAuthentication(request, association.getRawMacKey(), endpoint.getAlias());
    System.out.println(authentication);
```

Because i am not trying this for web app and I Dont have a callback-URL to use , i have use "easymock"

```
public HttpServletRequest createRequest(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int pos = url.indexOf('?');
    if (pos==(-1))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad url.");
    String query = url.substring(pos + 1);
    String[] params = query.split("[\\&]+");
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String param : params) {
        pos = param.indexOf('=');
        if (pos==(-1))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad url.");
        String key = param.substring(0, pos);
        String value = param.substring(pos + 1);
        map.put(key, URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }
    return (HttpServletRequest) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Main.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { HttpServletRequest.class },
            new InvocationHandler() {
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    if (method.getName().equals("getParameter"))
                        return map.get((String)args[0]);
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(method.getName());
                }


            }
    );
}
```

But I am getting a error saying ,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest is not visible from class loader
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:487)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:722)
```

---

and i have ALSO try as the code like in

https://gist.github.com/FernFerret/7692878 too (for Openid4java and spark) but got error when creating Route like in link saying there is no 'Route(String)'

```
get(new Route("/") {
```

---

So how can i Make OpenID authentication with out a Redirect URL ?

Can any one can guide me for a java OpenID Authentication for Steam using **"any"** OpenID code ?

I just need That returned value(  like-> http//steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561197960435530") informed in

http://steamcommunity.com/dev/

Which is the only value that returns .

Many Thanks For Any inputs !!